# How to setup Apache frontend for Websphere 8

Tags: java, apache, web-applications, websphere

I need to route requests to my application server through a http server.
I have gone through the IBM documentation but it seems very complex.

As far as I understand, these are the steps:

1. Install Apache server on separate machine
2. Install WAS on separate machine
3. Login to WAS console and Add Web Server
4. Install Apache WAS plugin in Apache server machine
5. Generate a plugin-config xml in WAS Console
6. Place the plugin-config file in the Apache WAS plugin folder

Is this roughly correct? Is there any requirement to add/edit virtual host for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your steps are correct. You don't need to edit virtual host aliases, if you will use default ports (*:80 and *:443, actually you can verify if *:443 is in default_host aliases, as for earlier versions you had to add it manually).

If you would use IBM Http Server (IHS), then you would have option to create admin service, which would propagate plugin-cfg file from WAS host to IHS host. In case of Apache you will have to copy it manually.

Once you have web server configured in the console, remember to map you applications to that web server also (via Enterprise Applications > applicationName > Manage modules). You will have to select BOTH - server1 and web server for your web modules. And then generate the plugin.

Links that might be useful for you:

- [Installing and configuring web server plug-ins - Overview](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tins_webplugins.html?lang=en)
- [Installing and uninstalling the Web Server Plug-ins on distributed](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tins_installation_plugins.html?lang=en)
- [Setting up a remote IHS web server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tihs_remotesetup.html?lang=en)